# Ingesting escape char string into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem where I'm using a stage to pick up a .csv file from Azure Blob Storage. This file contains strings enclosed by double quotes (") and double quotes in the string itself which are escaped (").

That all works fine, except there are strings containing just an escape character ("previous value","","next value"...). The quote is escaped but then it throws the following error:
Found character 'n' instead of field delimiter ','

I'm using ADF which doesn't escape the escape character (\). I've also tried transforming the copy into (for example: replace(s.$3, '\','\\')) but with no success.

My file format looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT CSV_FORMAT
    TYPE = CSV
    FIELD_DELIMITER = ','
    COMPRESSION = 'AUTO'
    RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
    SKIP_HEADER = 1
    TIME_FORMAT = 'HH12:MI:SS AM'
    TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
    ESCAPE = '\\'
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE
    ON_ERROR = CONTINUE
;
```

A sample of the csv that causes an issue:

```
234567,-234567,"B.V. Example, \"Company\"","nl","B.V. Example","00001293",1202,"",2007-09-01 15:20:46.0000000,"Admin",2018-07-23 15:17:02.0000000,"Admin"
123456,-123456,"\","nl","\","00001293",1202,"",2010-11-11 14:20:47.0000000,"Admin",2018-07-23 15:17:02.0000000,"Admin"
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide some exact sample data, obfuscating anything sensitive? Others may see it, but I'm having trouble seeing the exactly how the escaping and formatting in the source file is structured compared to the description of it. You can use the code block button `{}` to help format the source data sample. That will help to minimize changes to it and hopefully post it as is. You may need to ensure things like backslashes are preserved, and may need to double them to escape them.

Comment: I've put a part of the csv in the description

Comment: In your example, I don't see a legitimate reason for having an escape character defined.  Can you override it to something other than \?  That would resolve your issue for the example you've provided.

Comment: Good point, I have added another row that justifies the use of escape characters.

Comment: According to the rules, there are 10 columns in the top line and 12 in the second line. `B.V. Example, "Company"` is column 3 of the first line, and column three in the second line would be null. If that's just an artifact of the sample, I have an example to copy this type of formatting into a table. Let me know.

Comment: Sorry, the first line was missing 2 columns. The problem has to do with the "\" being read "\"," and then seeing the n instead of a column delimiter. How does one normally deal with a string that contains 1 escape character?